# WebClient fails to download AWS redirected content

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, http-redirect, webclient

Pasting the following url into your browser will allow you to download a zip file containing a nautical river chart and some schematic drawing of bridges existing along the river.

```
http://ienccloud.us/ienc/web/iencu37productsdownload.cfm?mode=0660&cell=U37AR126
```

However, the following code fails to download the zip file:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFile(@"http://ienccloud.us/ienc/web/iencu37productsdownload.cfm?mode=0660&cell=U37AR126", "download.zip");
}
```

but instead downloads the following plain text (html) file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Domain Names, Web Hosting and Online Marketing Services | Network Solutions</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Find domain names, web hosting and online marketing for your website -- all in one place. Network Solutions helps businesses get online and grow online with domain name registration, web hosting and innovative online marketing services.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="domain names, domain registration, web hosting, website host, hosting services, online marketing, network solutions, networksolutions.com, netsol">

        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
    <link rel="meta" href="http://www.https//www.networksolutions.com/labels.rdf" type="application/rdf+xml" title="ICRA labels" />
    <meta http-equiv="pics-Label" content='(pics-1.1 "http://www.icra.org/pics/vocabularyv03/" l gen true for "http://https//www.networksolutions.com" r (n 0 s 0 v 0 l 0 oa 0 ob 0 oc 0 od 0 oe 0 of 0 og 0 oh 0 c 1) gen true for "http://www.https//www.networksolutions.com" r (n 0 s 0 v 0 l 0 oa 0 ob 0 oc 0 od 0 oe 0 of 0 og 0 oh 0 c 1))' />
    <meta name="robots" content="noodp, noydir">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/ns.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ns.js" ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/template.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="page">
<div id="content">
        <div class="container"></div>
<div class="container">
            <div class="box first lrg news">
                <div id="productDetails" class="newsMain">
                    <div class="tagline-container">
                        <div class="tagline">Welcome to Network Solutions</div>
                        <p><a href="http://www.networksolutions.com">Go to Network Solutions</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clr"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My understanding is that the URL is a redirect and that the actual root hosting is AWS. It looks like some part of the redirect is going wonky, and I am not sure how to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

If possible, try using the new HttpClient library, it can handle redirects for you automatically like this:

```
HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler { AllowAutoRedirect = true };

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler, true);
```

It also gives you a lot more control than the old WebClient

Comment: This seems suitable, but unfortunately I'm not able to use .NET 4.5 in this context.

Comment: That's unfortunate, are you able to read headers in the WebClient? If so maybe you could handle the redirect yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You could also get it this way:

```
import requests
url = 'http://ienccloud.us/ienc/web/iencu37productsdownload.cfm?mode=0660&cell=U37AR126'
response = requests.get()
# the binary zip data is now in response.content
```

I'm not sure if this is .NET 4.5 compatible.